# How to Make a default value for IGrouping<TKey, TSource> with count = 0?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, grouping

I like C# linq and also the extension methods style.

Here is a simple code to get how **many times of each number is there in an array**:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
        var groups = nums.GroupBy(n => n);
        //var keynums = nums.Distinct();//ok
        var keynums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);//causes ArgumentNullException
        var timesDict = keynums.ToDictionary(n => n,
            n =>
            groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == n)
            //((groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == n))??what can be put here)
            .Count());
        foreach (var kv in timesDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}\t{string.Join(" ", kv.Value)}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The code works, but if I want know the nums are **always [0-9]**, and want to get how many times **[0-9]** appears (if not appears, the count should be **0**).

So the code will get `ArgumentNullException`, which makes sense because `FirstOrDefault` gets `null`.

So to fix this, I want to use the `??` operator, and give it a default value. but I cannot think of how to construct such value.

How would you solve it? please do not use other styles such as `if`, `select new {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using C#6 null-propagation like this?

```
groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == n)?.Count() ?? 0
```

if `FirstOrDefault` returns null, `?.Count()` will not be evaluated anymore and not throw an exception.

Comment: thanks! this works, and the `?.` operator seems to be introduced in C# 6, and later than `??`?

Comment: Yes, `??` has been around for a while, but the `?` operator was introduced in C#6. It makes the `??` operator all the more useful :)

Comment: You've got extra `)` in `== n))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
var higherLimits = new[] { 10, 20, 30 };
var ranges = items.GroupBy(item => higherLimits.First(higherLimits => higherLimits >= item));
```

This will avoid null issue altogether.

Comment: do you mean `GroupBy` can handle cases of `null` key?